# Are we correctly choosing our sample size?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

We have a set of 60000 files, and a we have a piece of software that attempts to look at each file and determine what date the contents pertain to.  We would like to be 99% confident that our software is selecting the correct date 95% +/- 5% of the time.

We manually created 658 tests that each take a file and the correct date, and verify if the software selected the correct date.  If 95% of our tests our passing have we met our 99% confidence mentioned above.  We got the number 658 using this calculator http://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm

Are we correctly applying statistics to our problem?
Thanks

Comment: (1) Is "95% +/- 5%" just a way of saying "at least 90%"? (2) Have you already done those 658 tests or are you asking whether this is the right number to use? (3) What are the consequences of selecting an incorrect date? Is it possible that a slightly incorrect date wouldn't be so bad, but hugely incorrect ones would? (4) What would the consequence be if it turned out the software actually performed worse than anticipated *in aggregate* on the 60,000 files (such as correctly identifying dates for only 89% of them, say)?

Comment: Answers: (1) Yes.  (2/3) We actually tag documents with more than just date, also who created the document (not necessarily who last edited it), and what type of document it is (based on templates, and organization structure that are only sometimes followed), we have varying numbers of tests right now for each tag (4) This is for in office file management, our goal is 90% before people start using it if users complain we will attempt to increase.  So small consequences.